# Is here have Balancer and NameResolver in gRPC with Python?

Tags: python, grpc, failover

I try to build a High available gRPC Client in Python with zookeeper  . But I can't find Balancer and NameResolver in Python . There are in Java and Go .

I know it can like this

```py
options = [('grpc.lb_policy_name', 'round_robin')]
channel = grpc.insecure_channel("ipv4:127.0.0.1:7777,127.0.0.1:8888", options=options,)
```

It can failover and balancing ,but the target is static . If I add a new server ,It can't found .And I want custom balancing policy .

So what should I do , Can we replace channel object when it's expection ? Or can we build our c-core , we have C++ and Python developer .

Answer (score 1):

These interfaces do not exist in Python, C++, or any of the gRPC implementations built on top of the C++-Core implementation. It *could* be done by adding in patches to the core to add a [name resolver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/660a860cff6296110b349e8591b74078af34e709/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver.h#L52) and [load balancing policy](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/660a860cff6296110b349e8591b74078af34e709/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy.h#L44).

However, all officially supported gRPC languages have recently added support for the [xDS protocol](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol) used by Envoy and Istio. It would also be possible to implement an xDS server performing your desired resolution. This could be done as a service sitting between Zookeeper and your gRPC clients. Compare with [this xDS server backed by Consul](https://github.com/gojek/consul-envoy-xds).

Comment: Consul itself provides a [service mesh](https://www.consul.io/use-cases/multi-platform-service-mesh) which, at quick glance, offers everything (and more) than what is provided by consul-envoy-xds. Thanks for that project though. Its another example of the industry gravitating toward the xDS API.